# How to delete a Cell from Collection View?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I want to delete cell from `UICollectionview`,when user `touchUpInside`(Button) to  remove cell.

**Here is my code:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    cell.deleteBtn?.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "Cdelete")
    cell.deleteBtn?.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("deleteColor:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project

    return cell
}

func deleteColor(sender:UIButton) {

    let i : Int = (sender.layer.value(forKey: "Cdelete")) as! Int
    self.items.remove(at: i)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**Where i am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set tag for your deletebutton for fetch the current cell/ know the which cell you tapped

```
cell.deleteBtn?.tag = indexPath.row
cell.deleteBtn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourVCName. deleteColor(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and call like

```
@IBAction func deleteColor(_ sender: UIButton){
   print("Button pressed  ")
  // continue your work

           var hitPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: yourCollectionViewName)
   var hitIndex: IndexPath? = yourCollectionViewName.indexPathForRow(at: hitPoint)

        self.items.remove(at: hitIndex.row)
          self.yourCollectionViewName.performBatchUpdates({
    self.yourCollectionViewName.deleteItems(at: [hitIndex])
}) { (finished) in
    self.yourCollectionViewName.reloadItems(at: self.yourCollectionViewName.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
}

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but steel getting error 
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value...
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Comment: in which line you faced this issue

Comment: in this line collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: i got the solution it was my mistak to set outlet of collectionview..Lol :-)

Comment: Calling `collectionView.reloadData()` will not show the desired rearrange animation. You will have to use `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` method. But after this method, all button tags are to refreshed to avoid inconsistency.

Comment: downvoteers, plz mention the mistake , it will useful for update the answer